# WPF Combobox issue. Dropdown content is blurred for a few seconds after opening it

Tags: wpf, combobox, controls

When you open the combo box, the text is blurry for a while.
If the minimum height is 30 pixels then everything is fine.
If there are more than two items then everything is fine.
It turns out if the pop-up window is less than 60 height then the problem.

I would like to understand what the problem is. (Solve it can set popup a minimum height of 60px, but this decision is not pleasant.)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="50">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125">
            <ComboBoxItem Height="24">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text item 1 Height 24"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="24">
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text item 2 Height 24"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125">
            <ComboBoxItem Height="30">
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text item 1"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Height="30">
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text item 2"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Picture example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogJZt.png)

[Picture example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmiVx.png)

Comment: Do not set the ComboBoxItem Height at all. Instead, set a Margin on the TextBlock.

Comment: If remove ComboBoxItem Height the result is the same (blurry text).                                                  <code>   <ComboBoxItem>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Text item 1 Height auto"/>
            </ComboBoxItem> <code>

Comment: This might be hardware related. You should test it on a different machine(s).